# Hexo2.3.0 command "yarn run dev" ERROR node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "Invalid Character"

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules, hexo

I was starting my project with a fresh Hexo folder version 2.3.0 (Which my senior programmer claimed that I can just extract, change its name to a project and start working on it) when I extracted the file, do
`yarn run init`
and everything's fine
but when I tried
`yarn run dev`

I get this error popup
[POPUP PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2RzY.png)

and also my terminal says this
[TERMINAL PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAXY5.png)

my webpack in node_module/webpack/bin/ looks like this

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.exitCode = 0;

/**
 * @param {string} command process to run
 * @param {string[]} args commandline arguments
 * @returns {Promise<void>} promise
 */
const runCommand = (command, args) => {
    const cp = require("child_process");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const executedCommand = cp.spawn(command, args, {
            stdio: "inherit",
            shell: true
        });

        executedCommand.on("error", error => {
            reject(error);
        });

        executedCommand.on("exit", code => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
};

/**
 * @param {string} packageName name of the package
 * @returns {boolean} is the package installed?
 */
const isInstalled = packageName => {
    try {
        require.resolve(packageName);

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
};

/**
 * @typedef {Object} CliOption
 * @property {string} name display name
 * @property {string} package npm package name
 * @property {string} binName name of the executable file
 * @property {string} alias shortcut for choice
 * @property {boolean} installed currently installed?
 * @property {string} url homepage
 * @property {string} description description
 */

/** @type {CliOption[]} */
const CLIs = [
    {
        name: "webpack-cli",
        package: "webpack-cli",
        binName: "webpack-cli",
        alias: "cli",
        installed: isInstalled("webpack-cli"),
        url: "https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli",
        description: "The original webpack full-featured CLI."
    },
    {
        name: "webpack-command",
        package: "webpack-command",
        binName: "webpack-command",
        alias: "command",
        installed: isInstalled("webpack-command"),
        url: "https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-command",
        description: "A lightweight, opinionated webpack CLI."
    }
];

const installedClis = CLIs.filter(cli => cli.installed);

if (installedClis.length === 0) {
    const path = require("path");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const readLine = require("readline");

    let notify =
        "One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:";

    for (const item of CLIs) {
        notify += `\n - ${item.name} (${item.url})\n   ${item.description}`;
    }

    console.error(notify);

    const isYarn = fs.existsSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "yarn.lock"));

    const packageManager = isYarn ? "yarn" : "npm";
    const installOptions = [isYarn ? "add" : "install", "-D"];

    console.error(
        `We will use "${packageManager}" to install the CLI via "${packageManager} ${installOptions.join(
            " "
        )}".`
    );

    let question = `Which one do you like to install (${CLIs.map(
        item => item.name
    ).join("/")}):\n`;

    const questionInterface = readLine.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stderr
    });
    questionInterface.question(question, answer => {
        questionInterface.close();

        const normalizedAnswer = answer.toLowerCase();
        const selectedPackage = CLIs.find(item => {
            return item.name === normalizedAnswer || item.alias === normalizedAnswer;
        });

        if (!normalizedAnswer) {
            console.error(
                "One CLI needs to be installed alongside webpack to use the CLI."
            );
            process.exitCode = 1;

            return;
        } else if (!selectedPackage) {
            console.error(
                "No matching choice.\n" +
                    "One CLI needs to be installed alongside webpack to use the CLI.\n" +
                    "Try to installing your CLI of choice manually."
            );
            process.exitCode = 1;

            return;
        }

        const packageName = selectedPackage.package;

        console.log(
            `Installing '${
                selectedPackage.name
            }' (running '${packageManager} ${installOptions.join(
                " "
            )} ${packageName}')...`
        );

        runCommand(packageManager, installOptions.concat(packageName))
            .then(() => {
                require(packageName); //eslint-disable-line
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                process.exitCode = 1;
            });
    });
} else if (installedClis.length === 1) {
    const path = require("path");
    const pkgPath = require.resolve(`${installedClis[0].package}/package.json`);
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
    const pkg = require(pkgPath);
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
    require(path.resolve(
        path.dirname(pkgPath),
        pkg.bin[installedClis[0].binName]
    ));
} else {
    console.warn(
        `You have installed ${installedClis
            .map(item => item.name)
            .join(
                " and "
            )} together. To work with the "webpack" command you need only one CLI package, please remove one of them or use them directly via their binary.`
    );
}
```

pls send help

And also, I'm new on StackOverflow as a user, so henlo.

EDIT1: You can reproduce the error by downloading this repo and do `yarn run init` followed by `yarn run dev` with node.js version 6.12.2 (It's the version that works for my senior programmer) [Error Code Repository](https://github.com/gogogo97/Hexo2.3.0-InvalidCharacter)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! It seems that you are not running the script in the correct NodeJS environment. Maybe you ask your senior programmer (who told you to just "extract the and work on it") for setting up your dev environment.

Comment: Got it!!! I got docker lesson from him and I got a new dev environment